# SQL Join involving 3 tables, how to?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

SQL newbie here.

So we have 3 tables:

```
categories(cat_id,name);   
products(prod_id,name);
relationships(prod_id,cat_id);
```

It is a one-to-many relationship.

So, given a category name say "Books". How do I find all the products that come under books?

As an example,

```
categories(1,Books);  
categories(2,Phones);  
products(302,Sherlock Holmes);  
relationships(302,1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join tables on related columns and specify `WHERE` clause to select all records where category name = `'Books'`

```
SELECT p.*
FROM categories c
JOIN relationships r ON c.cat_id = r.cat_id
JOIN products p ON r.prod_id = p.prod_id
WHERE c.name = 'Books' -- or specify parameter like @Books
```

Comment: ok, we do have FTS enabled so I will have to add the match( ) in `where`?

Comment: @LittleChild what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Your query worked like magic, btw :) Since I have to use it to match user-given search, I am trying to use FTS instead of like hence my questions :)

Comment: To use user given string you could pass variable, something like: `WHERE c.name = @searchString`

Comment: fair enough.. but `@searchString` will need to be escaped, right? if it has a `'` in it, it'll open up SQL injection

Comment: For example to avoid *SQL Injection* in *PHP* you could use `mysql_real_escape_string` and if you'll use `@parameter` you'll be safe against *SQL Injection* anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `JOIN` the three tables.

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM relationships r
INNER JOIN products p
    ON p.prod_id = r.prod_id
INNER JOIN categories c
    ON c.cat_d = r.cat_id
WHERE c.name = 'Books'
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you often join related tables and beginners tend to join, whatever the situation. I would not recommend this. In your case you want to select products. If you only want to show products data, select from products only. You want to select products that are **in** the category 'Books' (or for which **exists** an entry in category 'Books'). Hence use an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause in order to find them:

```
select * from products
where prod_id in
(
  select prod_id
  from relationships
  where cat_id = (select cat_id from categories where name = 'Books')
);
```

Thus you get a well structured query that tells the reader easily how the tables are related and what data you are actually interested in. Later, with different tables and data to select, this may keep you from duplicate result rows that you must get rid of by using `DISTINCT` or from getting wrong aggregates (sums, counts, etc.), because of mistakenly considering records multifold.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select p.Prod_id,p.name 
from products p inner join relationships r on 
p.prod_id = r.prod_id
where r.cat_id = (select cat_id from categories where name = 'books')
```

or

```
select p.Prod_id,p.name 
from products p inner join relationships r on 
p.prod_id = r.prod_id inner join categories c on c.cat_id = r.cat_id
where c.name = 'books'
```